# Why are fund managers' average/minimum purchase price from form 13F the same?

Tags: stocks, investing

Using the fund managers 13F form filings you can calculate the average, minimum, and number of shares of a stock they listed for each quarter.

Looking at the data to see who buy/add/reduce/sold out AAPL last quarter (2013-03-31) and performing the calculations resulted in all their average and minimum prices for AAPL being:

`Average: $467.26,
Minimum: $420.05`

The following links also list their average and minimum price for AAPL as the same:

source: http://www.nasdaq.com/article/t-rowe-price-equity-income-fund-buy-low-and-sell-high-apa-aapl-wu-joy-nem-sells-cag-amgn-cm238170

source: http://www.gurufocus.com/StockBuy.php?GuruName=David+Einhorn

Why in this example (and in general) do all 13F form filers have the same average and minimum price for a given stock during that quarter?

EDIT: @Joe Coder Guy, I thought that might be the case too. But looking at several other ticker symbols it was the same story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GuruFocus Link is just reporting the high and low price of the quarter.

> Price Range (Average) – The estimated trade prices. The average price
>   is calculated from the time weighted average during the period. If no
>   price range is shown, the trade prices are estimated trade prices,
>   which are more accurate estimates.
>
> AAPL: $420.05 - $549.03 ($467.26)

The numbers for the high and low match what I found for AAPL on Yahoo Finance. Keep in mind their definition uses estimate 3 times.